# Create random double, unified over whole range of valid doubles

Tags: c#, random, double

There is [Best way to generate a random float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365337/best-way-to-generate-a-random-float-in-c-sharp) for float, and [Generating a Random Decimal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609501/generating-a-random-decimal-in-c-sharp) for decimal, however, there is no question for double yet which covers "the full range of double".

How to properly generate a random double with a uniform distribution over all valid (i.e., non-NaN/infinite/...) values?

Comment: What do you mean by uniform distribution? Do you want each double to be equally likely, or do you want a mathematically uniform distribution (i.e., the chance of getting a number in the interval `[x, y]` is proportional to `(y-x)`)?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. How does calling `random.NextDouble()` and then scaling that to the range `[double.MinValue, double.MaxValue]` not address your need? Why don't you just apply the answer for `float` you found, but use the `double` type instead? Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: ad float) I'm not sure how to apply the answer for double as nobody describes where the constants come from (*2.0, -1.0, -126, +128)

Comment: ad scaling) how to do that? The old `rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble() ` does not work as it runs into overflows if r.nextDouble() is very high.

Comment: ad distribution) I'd like it to have the same distribution as nextDouble() has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scaling wouldn't work, because the scaling factor would be actually bigger than double.MaxValue which doesn't work.

```
var number = r.NextDouble() * 2d - 1d; // r in [-1, 1]
return number * double.MaxValue;
```

This code snippet first generates a uniform distributed random number in the range [-1,1].
Than it transforms it into your desired range.

This only works, when both ranges are equal, which is true for your use-case ( `double.MaxValue == Math.Abs(double.MinValue)`)

Note: actually the upper bound of Random.NextDouble() is 0.99999999999999978 according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.7)

According to your question, how to get a range where 1 is included, you could implement the `random.NextDouble()` method on your own.
The reference implementation (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca) uses the Random.Next() method and maps it to a double, where the `Random.Next()` method has a range `[0, Int32.MaxValue - 1]`. So just use `r.Next() * (1.0 / (Int32.MaxValue - 1))` which would return double values in the range `[0, 1]`.

By the way, I don't think, the docs are correct, since the maximum value, `Random.NextDouble()` can generate is `0.999999999534339`, which is `(Int32.MaxValue - 1) * (1.0 / Int32.MaxValue)` and not `0.99999999999999978`.

Comment: Sounds great - I'm just a little bit concerned about 1 not being in range. So the algorithm never outputs `double.MaxValue` as the result. Do you think it is possible to alter the `2d` factor to something a little bit bigger so that 1 is also included in the range?