# way to generate a negative random Double in C#

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random Number Between 2 Double Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064901/random-number-between-2-double-numbers)

I want to generate a number between -8.000 and -3100.000.

How can this be achieved?

Whats the most efficient code?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064901/random-number-between-2-double-numbers

Answer (score 6):

Here's the standard way to produce a random number within a range.  Note that I'm producing several to illustrate that you don't want to create a new RNG for each one when using a pseudorandom number generator to avoid situations where they can have the same seed value.

```
var rng = new Random();
var randoms = new double[10];
double MIN_VALUE = -3100.0;
double MAX_VALUE = -8.0;

for (var int i = 0; i < randoms.Length; ++i)
{
    randoms[i] = rng.NextDouble() * (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: 0.5 * (-8 - (-3100)) + (-3100) = 0.5 * 3092 - 3100 = 1546 - 3100 = -1554.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty standard answer one will get after asking this question is to do

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double MIN_VALUE = -3100.0;
double MAX_VALUE = -8.0;

double random_value = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + MIN_VALUE;
```

However, I'm afraid that's not 100% correct. Ok, it depends on what you mean by *"a number between"*. And here's why:

`Random.NextDouble Method` returns *"a double-precision floating point number greater than or equal to `0.0`, and less than `1.0`."* (as described in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx))

So, since `rnd.NextDouble()` returns a number in range `[0; 1)`, when you do

```
rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + MIN_VALUE
```

you will get a random number in range `[MIN_VALUE; MAX_VALUE)` (`MAX_VALUE` exclusively). If that's what you wanted, then great. But what if you wanted a random number in range `[MIN_VALUE; MAX_VALUE]` (`MAX_VALUE` inclusively - which I believe you did)?

Well, I don't know how to do that with double numbers of great precision. So, I'm gonna assume that when you wrote *"-8.000"* and *"-3100.000"* what you meant by that was that you want a 0.001 precision in the randomly generated number. This is how I would try to achieve that:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double MIN_VALUE = -3100.0;
double MAX_VALUE = -8.0;
int PRECISION = 1000;

int min = (int)(MIN_VALUE * PRECISION);    //I know these could be sent as arguments to rnd.Next(),
int max = (int)(MAX_VALUE * PRECISION);    //but I wanted to keep it easier to read and understand

double random_value = rnd.Next(min, max + 1);    //[-3100000; -8000]
random_value /= PRECISION;
```

That would give you a random number in a range `[-3100.000; -8.000]`.

If I would use `rnd.Next(min, max)` then the result would be in range `[-3100.000; -8.001]`, and that's because `Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)` returns *"A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue."* (see [`Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx).

And last thing, if you're using `rnd.NextDouble()` method, and you have to generate huge amount of random numbers within a range [Min, Max], and you're doing it in a loop, you might want to consider taking `MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE` out of the loop (or embedded loops). No need to calculate this every single time.

```
double MAX_MINUS_MIN = MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < BIG_SCARY_NUMBER; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < BIG_SCARY_NUMBER; ++j)
        for (int k = 0; k < BIG_SCARY_NUMBER; ++k)
            randoms[i, j, k] = rnd.NextDouble() * MAX_MINUS_MIN + MIN_VALUE;
```