# Generate random doubles between negative and positive infinity in c#

Tags: c#, random, double

How can I generate random doubles between negative and positive infinity in c# (full span of values of double type)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064901/random-number-between-2-double-numbers
and use the max representable pos and neg doubles in C#

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064901/random-number-between-2-double-numbers

Comment: What do you want want to do this for?

Comment: Technically this has not been answered yet, since the answer provided in the "duplicate" will not work if your minimum value is negative and your maximum value is positive.